# Declare empty array, populate and iterate troubles - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, console

I wrote a script to read the Netflix catalog and populate my DB.  **Everything worked fine as a web script** (except for timeouts) so I shifted to **calling directly from the console**.

I noticed a few oddities, like __construct() no longer being called (but that was easily remedied using the class name as a function.

Now I **can't get my arrays to work as before**, here's the general idea.

(Actually I have tried a few combinations, so I'll share them all)

1 - this worked in the web script version just fine, no longer works calling from console

```
//declare empty
var $genreArray=array();

//later I add values one at a time as the XML is parsed
array_push($this->genreArray,$attrs['term']);

//after I have parsed an entire "title" element, I iterate the array
foreach ($this->genreArray as $value) {
    // never gets called - array seen as empty
    $this->db->linkGenre($value,$this->title_uid);
}
```

2 - so I tried the PHP manual; recommendation - nothing

```
//declare empty
var $genreArray=array();

//later I add values one at a time as the XML is parsed
$this->genreArray[]=$attrs['term'];

//after I have parsed an entire "title" element, I iterate the array
foreach ($this->genreArray as $value) {
    // never gets called - array seen as empty
    $this->db->linkGenre($value,$this->title_uid);
}
```

3 - so finally I tried manually tracking the index

```
//declare empty array
var $genreArray=array();
var $gi=0;

//later I add values one at a time as the XML is parsed
$this->genreArray[$this->gi++]=$attrs['term'];

//after I have parsed an entire "title" element, I iterate the array
foreach ($this->genreArray as $value) {
    // never gets called - array seen as empty
    $this->db->linkGenre($value,$this->title_uid);
}
```

So I am totally stumped now.

Has anyone declared empty arrays and populated via console?

(All 3 of these work via the web - so I need a console expert here)

---

**Thanks for the support, here are the additional details requested;**

php -v

PHP 4.4.9 (cli) (built: Sep 17 2008 12:02:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Extension Manager v1.2.2, Copyright (c) 2003-2007, by Zend Technologies
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2007, by Zend Technologies

---

Each snippet was tried in a separate run. What details about the class are you interested in?

I have used echo statements to verify that the code is being called as expected. And if I hit the script through a URL everything kicks off fine (for the first few thousand records until the timeout).

---

No errors are being thrown, I even tried adding...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: Are all those snippets part of a class?

Comment: Indeed, what's the rest of the class look like?

Comment: What values does the $attrs['term'] holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed a few oddities, like __construct() no longer being called (but that was easily remidied using the class name as a function.

It sounds like your command-line and web server PHP are different versions. Is your CLI PHP 4? The function `phpversion()` will tell you the version in both CLI and web.

Have you checked your error log? You didn't mention it, but that would be the first place to look.

Comment: Nice catch. But I doubt that is the problem otherwise the array stuff would work, even in PHP 4.

Comment: CLI was php 4, by calling php5 explicitly everything cooked along fine!

Thank you!

Comment: @Eddie: Still the script should work in PHP 4, were you using SimpleXML or any other PHP 5 specific extension?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed a few oddities, like
>   __construct() no longer being called (but that was easily remidied using
>   the class name as a function.

This seems weird. What PHP version were you using in the web script and what version in the console?

Typing php -v will tell you the version.

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid the non-CLI timeout you can do something like this:**

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

---

You seem to be using `var` instead of `public` for the class property declarations, that together with the fact that you can't use `__construct()` makes me guess you're using PHP 4, is that right?

Where is `$attrs['term']` declared?

Try doing `var_dump($attrs['term']);` to see what comes up.

One other thing that doesn't smell right is the following lines:

```
array_push($this->genreArray,$attrs['term']);
$this->genreArray[]=$attrs['term'];
$this->genreArray[$this->gi++]=$attrs['term'];
```

`$attrs['term']` seems to be an array, but you aren't looping through it. Unless those lines are in a separate method of it's own I think something is wrong there.

Also, is the code you provided us part of a class? Just to make sure..

Comment: Alix. $attrs is the list of attributes for an xml element, I am only concerned witht he term, so i need not iterate that array. It could just as well be a string "foo", and it was indeed being popualterd correctly by the parser.

Anyway Ben was right on, my CLI versino was 4, which doesn't seem to play the way I was used to in m y web version 5.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `var` from `var $genreArray=array();`

I had the same problem and removing `var` fixed it.

Comment: This question was asked and answered 18 months ago